# collection_select promt/default value in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have:

```
<%= collection_select(:name, :room_id, @room, :id, :name, class: "select optional", prompt: 'Add New Room') %>
```

On a user select, the ID of the room is passed to a script that makes the div with that ID holding the edit form visibile.  I want to have an "Add New Room" option, which will show the form to create a new room.  The problem is the "Add New Room" selector has no value associated with it, which means I have trouble building the div for that item.  Is there anyway to give that a value or to more generically add an option to the select menu?